# Definir porcentagem de branco e preto em uma foto trabalhada em BW

Tags: matlab

Eu quero saber a porcentagem de que cor é mais predominante na foto. O preto ou o branco?

]([image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xU3VW.jpg])

Comment: Coloque na pergunta um [mcve] mostrando o que fez até o momento.

Comment: Oi Raquel parece ser simples de fazer isso no matlab heimm é possível de fazer com poucas linhas, o que vc já tentou fazer ?